# I am getting chrome://invalid when I use __MSG_@@extension_id__ in my CSS file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building a chrome extension with `Manifest V3`. I am using the below-given snippet in my CSS file to load local fonts.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'PoppinsLight';
    src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/Fonts/Poppins-Light.ttf');
}
```

When I load it into my browser, I get this error

```
Request URL: chrome-extension://invalid/
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I have also added `web_accessible_resources` in my Manifest. So, no problem at that end.

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: Reload the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing manifest.json. Also make sure the path is correct and the uppercase letters match the source.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I've tried everything, literally.

Just to be sure, the only changes I have made are in the manifest file, where I've added web_accessible_resources, and in the CSS file, where I've added __MSG_@@extension_id__. There's nothing else I need to do, right?

Comment: I am replacing the ```__MSG_@@extension_id__``` in the CSS file with the actual extension ID and that's working great. 

But, I guess hardcoding the ID is not the right way to go about it.

Comment: How do you load the CSS file?

Comment: I am using Webpack to with the ```css-loader``` to load CSS. It's a React app.

Comment: MSG works only if you load the css file via a `link` DOM element so if you load it differently you'll have to patch the text manually and replace all `"chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/"` with `chrome.runtime.getURL('/')` in JS.

Comment: Oh didn't know that.

So, how can I load the fonts using JS instead of CSS? Also, can you please mention the link to the docs where you found that information? I have been looking all over but didn't come across that anywhere.

Comment: I don't know how it's done in React and I don't have any links. One guess though: it may be the result of injecting your code as a script element or using `world: 'MAIN'`.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this? I am facing the same issue.@AdityaKrishna

Comment: @Sid No, I didn't get any solution to this problem. However, I have figured out a workaround.

You can host your extension and make it private. This way, you'll get a permanent extension id. Now you can hardcode it like chrome-extension://hjkafshdjfhljflajs789 instead of using chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__.

Comment: @AdityaKrishna Thanks.  In my case I have to deploy my extension at multiple PCs, If I make it private, still it going to maintain same id across all machines? If is it, then could you please tell me how to make it private?

Comment: @Siddhesh You can't make it private as far as I know. To make it private, you'll have to upload the extension first on the chrome extension store. In the dashboard, you have the option to make your app private.